# Can execCommand or a similar function be used to set, rather than to toggle, a simple style like bold?

Tags: javascript, contenteditable

If a contenteditable div's contents are already bold, then execCommand("bold") will remove the bold style.

That's great in normal circumstances, but I have a situation where I'd like to loop through a bunch of contenteditable divs and set any non-bold text to bold, sort of a way to style multiple rich text elements at once, using the proper  or  or 'font-weight' whatevers that execCommand uses.

I can do it a hard way by scrutinizing each node in each div in isolation, but I want to make sure there isn't a simpler way first.

Comment: If it is the entire contents of an element, you can use CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I couldn't find an easy way, so I did it the hard way.

I already had a function that copied the contents of a single element to a working space div with clean CSS, and then recursed through each node within that working space.  For each text node, it would loop through each style I'm looking for and see if that style is set.  If it's NOT, it would clear an "every node has this style" flag set before its run.  So I ended up with a list of every style set for every node.

The first step for this current task was to identify which styles applied to all selected elements.  So I took that function and created a modified version that first added each element's contents to the working space div.  Then it ran the normal recursive walk through the working space, basically treating each separate element as if they're part of the same complex rich text string.

That gave me the status of each style, like whether everything was bold and thus the bold button should show as pressed.

I also added an array for each style.  As I recursed through the elements, tracking their individual "every node has this style" value, I would come up with a list of elements where every node had the style, and thus execcommand("bold") would toggle that element.

So now, for each style (like for the bold button), I knew whether it would toggle any elements, or all elements.  If it would toggle all elements, or no elements, then that's fine because the behavior's consistent.  But if it toggled a subset of elements (if "elements_that_would_toggle" array length for a style was greater than zero but less than the total_elements count), then I would ignore those toggle-able elements on the first button click.

At the end of that click processing, I then blank out those arrays for each style, thus reverting the behavior across the board to toggling, because now every element has been set to the same status.

It's sort of a disgusting approach, but it's controlled and consistent, and it works really well.

And it only took a day to get working.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how complex the editor you are making is. If you don't want to allow normal text inside a bold region, it may be enough to test only the deepest containers of editable texts, so one element for each of the editable divs.

Here's an example,

```
function bold(node) {
  var selection = window.getSelection();
  var range = document.createRange();

  range.selectNodeContents(node);

  selection.removeAllRanges();
  selection.addRange(range);

  if (!isBold(getDeepestContainer(selection.anchorNode)))
    document.execCommand("bold");

  selection.removeAllRanges();
  node.blur();
}

function getDeepestContainer(node) {
  var result = node;

  while (result.childNodes.length === 1) {
    result = result.firstChild;
  }

  if (result instanceof Element)
    return result;

  return result.parentElement;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NqZQzR?editors=101